# Issue with model classes after database updates,

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, jooq, speedment

I have created one application which can able to perform a DML operation on database. Now there is one condition the user created new table in that database(by using front-end) but that table is not accessible due to model class is not available, so there is any type of Framework in JAVA which can able to perform this type of operations without respective model classes dependencies.

**In short there is any framework which handle all types of DLL and DML operation without model classes?
i know its stupid question.**

Comment: I think it's a good question and would like to know the same.

Comment: You can use pure JDBC for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll provide an answer for a few APIs that you've tagged your question with, plus JDBC:

#### JPA

JPA requires a model at compile time (technically at the time when you load the entities), so it doesn't work well with ad-hoc models like yours. You could, of course, use runtime Java compilation and load those runtime generated entities dynamically, but that seems quite complicated.

#### jOOQ

jOOQ can work that way as stated e.g. in the tutorial. You can use jOOQ:

- [without code generation](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/use-cases/jooq-as-a-standalone-sql-builder/)
- [with code generation](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/use-cases/jooq-as-a-sql-builder-with-code-generation/)

In jOOQ, generated code is completely optional, adding additional type safety to your client code, but you don't have to use it. All DDL and DML statements can be expressed with [ad-hoc identifiers](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/names/), or even [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/).

#### JDBC

When using Java/Spring/etc. you can always resort to using JDBC, the lower level API that is used by most of the above APIs behind the scenes. In Spring, there's also a thin API on top of JDBC called `JdbcTemplate`, which makes using JDBC a bit more convenient.

(Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ)

Comment: Thanks a lot @lukas that is what I am looking for